# Large batch insertions: how to get INSERT SQL code from Grails?

Tags: sql, grails, batch-file, grails-orm, bulkinsert

I had a lot of troubles with large insert batches on Grails. I tried all the most common workarounds proposed by users (such as the WithTransaction, etc), and the insertions were still ridiculously slow.

I have a batch with about 500K objects. On Gorm, the object creation/insertion in the DB performs at about 200ms per insert, which is obviously not acceptable.
If I generate the relevant SQL INSERT statements from the app in a dump file, and then I run the dump file directly on the DBMS, I get < 1ms per insert, which is more like it.
In order to make the batch online, I'm thinking of this solution (pseudo Groovy code):

```
FileBuffer sqlFile = ...
largeBatch.each{
    def obj = createMyObject( it )
    String sql = getSQL code for obj insert
    sqlFile.write( sql )
}
execute sqlFile directly on JDBC
```

How can I get the insert SQL code from a transient object?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to performing faster batch processing for inserting data:

1. hibernate stateless session (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)
2. native sql (http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) (create x insert statements and fire them in x database transactions) e.g. you can create one single sql dump and fire this dump in one single transaction.

with hibernate stateless session you can also batch the inserts and can insert a domain class instance e.g. session.save(obj). with navite sql you have to build the statements by your own.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to extract the SQL code that Hibernate generates within GORM?

Answer (score 0):

[Ted Naleid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8912/ted-naleid)'s got a [good write-up](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/) on improving batch insert/update performance. Have you come across it? His suggestions have worked for me for batch updates.

Here's an excerpt from lower down in the article:

> Normally, a grails hibernate session
>   executes something quickly and
>   returns. During importing, we do a ton
>   of processing, all with the same
>   hibernate session. All of these
>   objects that would normally be garbage
>   collected when the session closed are
>   piling up.
>
> The easiest way to deal with this is
>   to create a simple method to clear out
>   these collections periodically.

He suggests periodically flushing and clearing the session.

```
data.eachWithIndex { datum, index ->
    // insert or update datum
    if(index % 100 == 0) {
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession()
        session.flush()
        session.clear()
        // also clear the Grails domain class property instance map
        // - it may be that this isn't necessary anymore; not sure, but the article is
        //   a bit old, so maybe it's been fixed within Grails.
    }
}
```

Using this, he improves a batch insert of 100k records from ~2.5 hours to 3 minutes.

*@Ted - If you come across this question/answer and would like to repeat this answer yourself, I'd be more than happy to delete my answer and upvote yours; you did all of the hard work figuring it out. Thanks!*

Comment: I tried that solution and I also have a memory leak. I'm sick of GORM at this stage, so I think in this case I'll generate SQL and run it offline on the dbms. I was just wondering if there was a clever find to get the SQL generated from hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Hibernate Configuration subclass to capture the SQL that's generated at startup. I'm not sure what the best way to access it later would be - perhaps a public static field in the class.

Here's the code (put it under src/java):

```
package com.yourcompany.yourapp;

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;

public class DdlCapturingConfiguration extends GrailsAnnotationConfiguration {

   @Override
   public String[] generateSchemaCreationScript(Dialect d) throws HibernateException {
      String[] sql = super.generateSchemaCreationScript(d);
      // do something with the sql
      return sql;
   }
}
```

and you'd register it in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy` like this:

```
dataSource {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = ...
   username = ...
   password = ...
   dialect = ...
   configClass = com.yourcompany.yourapp.DdlCapturingConfiguration
}
```